# Is there a more effecient way to determine if two EntityCollections contain the same elements?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to determine if two EntityCollections are equal.  I have code I think will do the trick, but I'm wondering if there might be a more effecient algorithm?  Note, the EntityCollections will likely have less than 10 elements each.

```
    private static bool isEquivalent(
        EntityCollection<MyClassDetails> myClassDetails1,
        EntityCollection<MyClassDetails> myClassDetails2 )
    {
        var myClassComparer = new MyClassComparer();

        return
            myClassDetails1.All(
                myClassDetail1 =>
                 myClassDetails2.Contains(
                    myClassDetail1, myClassComparer ) );
    }

    class MyClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClassDetails>
    {
        public bool Equals( MyClassDetails details1, MyClassDetails details2 )
        {
            return details1.DetailID == details2.DetailID;
        }

        public int GetHashCode( MyClassDetails obj )
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this determine if the intersection of two collections is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to start with, if your collections will likely only hold 10 elements each then it's probably premature to be worrying about efficiency of this algorithm, unless you're calling it a lot in a critical path. But one thing you could try is to use the Intersects and Any extensions instead.

```
return !myClassDetails1.Intersects(myClassDetails2, new MyClassComparer()).Any();
```

I'm not sure how much more efficient it would be but the code would be prettier. Also, in the past I have created an FuncComparer for just such an occasion.

```
class FuncComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
  private Func<bool, T, T> compare;
  public FuncComparer(Func<boo, T, T> compare){
    this.compare = compare;
  }
  public bool Equals(T left, T right) {
    return this.compare(left, right);
  }
}

// usage
return !items1
  .Intersects(items2, new FuncComparer<Item>((l, r) => l.Id == r.Id))
  .Any();
```

Comment: I do like this solution, which is probably what @dlev's comment was alluding to.  I think it will be less effecient because it always iterates through all elements, but for the small number of elements I expect to have it probably won't be an issue.

Comment: This should not iterate over every element in the case of a failure. Any() will stop immediately if a single item is returned from interestects, it will not continue to iterate. Also intersects does not need to completely iterate before it will return. That is the power of co-routines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'll be traversing the array each time through your main loop (.All). If you used linq to sort them (orderby) you could then just loop through one list and compare the item to the item at the same index in the other list. In fact you could return `false` as soon as you hit a difference.

Comment: That is a good point.  If I can have the server OrderBy DetailID on both collections then I can return as soon I find a difference.

Comment: No, the All() method will stop iterating after the first failure.

Comment: would getting the server to order the list improve the performance of Contains?